# Using ng-options on array declared in an object

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

In my controller, I have:

```
 $scope.sizes = {
    things: [
        'one',
        'two'
        ]
}
```

and in my HTML, I have

```
  <select ng-options="thing for thing in sizes.things"></select>
```

The resulting combobox has no values. However, in this case:

```
 $scope.things = ['one', 'two'];

  <select ng-options="thing for thing in things"></select>
```

The resulting combobox shows "one", "two" as its options. Can someone explain why I can't access the array within a $scope object?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it should be a problem.  Can you demonstrate the problem in a jsFiddle (or some other online demo tool)?

Comment: sure! [here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/1120/)

Comment: Are you really using Angularjs 1.0.3?

Comment: that fiddle is broken.  angular is never being bootstrapped, and if you are using 1.4, that's definitely not the way to declare a controller.

Comment: ng-options has had a number of breaking changes over the life of angular, so if you are trying to demonstrate an issue, you should ensure that you are showing code that is compatible with the version you are trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the `ng-model` attribute on your [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) select element.

Adding `ng-model="thing"` gets it working...

```
<select ng-model="thing" ng-options="thing for thing in sizes.things"></select>
```

You can see a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/1122/).

PS It was actually not working for either the array or the object.  Adding the `ng-model` attribute gets both working.